# HIVE HQL is there a way to use user variable in SELECT as MySQL does?

Tags: hiveql

Under MySQL, when I am doing :

```
SELECT @a:=concat("he","llo"),concat(@a," world")
```

I get "hello world".
It is very useful because you don't have to rebuild "hello" in the second field and if I wish to modify the first "concat", it will affect the second...
With complex constructions, the gain is obvious I think...

But I didn't find the same way in HiveQL and so far, I am forced to rewrite each field construction...
I know that a subselect would do the same thing but I would prefer to avoid this way (for some practical reasons...).

Comment: it seems that it is possible to do it through "SET hivevar" instruction, I am trying it...

Comment: it works ! by doing : "SET hivevar:your_var=concat(field1,"-",field2)" and "SELECT ${your_var} FROM..."